# How do i access an image from the node.js sharp module buffer

Tags: node.js, module, buffer, sharp

I'm new to node.js and web development and have a question regarding the node.js sharp module. I want to resize/crop an image using the node.js sharp module, store it to a buffer and access it afterwards. 
After reading the [Sharp API](http://sharp.dimens.io/en/stable/api-output/#tobuffer) I came up with this code example.

```
sharp('img.jpg').extract(extract).resize(height, width).toBuffer(function (err, data, info) {img = data;});
```

I thought that the variable img now contains my new image.
My first question would be whether my assumption is correct.
If this is correct, how can i display the new image on my website? If possible, I would like to use an HTML img tag. But if there are better and easier ways, feel free to let me know. I don't want to store the image to a local file.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. You first need to save your image on your disk with fs for example ->

```
const   saveImageOnDisk = (base64Image, imageName) => 
{
    const   buf = new Buffer(base64Image.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ''), 'base64');

    fs.writeFile(`./${imageName}.png`, buf, {encoding: 'base64', flag: 'w'}, err => console.warn(err));
};
```

And then, you can try to access this image by doing some operation with Sharp (ex. on a node server to display the image)

```
exports.getImage = (req, res) =>
{
    const   fileName = `./${req.params.image}`;
    const   width = 200;
    const   height = 200;

    sharp(fileName)
    .resize(height, width)
    .toBuffer()
    .then((data) =>
    {
        //To display the image
        res.writeHead(200, {
            'Content-Type': 'image/png',
            'Content-Length': data.length
        });
        return (res.end(data));
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

So, with a route like this

```
app.route('/myImages/:image').get(Methods.getImage);
```

You can access your image with you simple url -> http://yourserver.xyz/myImages/imageX